# US Treasury foreign buying/selling data

Tags: fixed-income, bond, treasuries

Would anyone recommend any Index or data that I can avail to understand the trend in buying/selling of US treasuries by China? I have access to Reuters feed.

Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link from Treasury gives you the data you need 
https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/tic/Pages/index.aspx